# customize QR code with rounded corners for QR code edges instead of square and want to change color of code android?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing, rounded-corners

I have generated simple black with square corners for QR code using `com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3`.
I want to customize QR code appearance like Instagram.
[This library is used at many places](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja1kc.png) https://github.com/scola/Qart

How to make square edges rounded? like below image :

[image]

Comment: You can make custom preview class extends with _ViewFinderView_

Comment: @Piyush can you elaborate more?

Comment: managed to do like this how to format circles ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69219627/how-to-replace-3-squares-to-circle-in-qr-code-to-using-paint-android-to-customiz

Answer (score -1):

You can create custom class like

```
private static class CustomViewFinderView extends ViewFinderView {
    public final Paint PAINT = new Paint();

    public CustomViewFinderView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomViewFinderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // paint initialization
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

       // Here you can draw your view using canvas with edges
     }
     }
```

After that while you initialize your `ZXingScannerView` add your custom view in `createViewFinderView` method.

```
   ZXingScannerView mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this) {
        @Override
        protected IViewFinder createViewFinderView(Context context) {
            return new CustomViewFinderView(context);
        }
    };
```